# Regex Of A String that Must Contain Certain Letters

Tags: regex

I'm supposed to design a regex over the alphabet {A, B, ... Z} that contains at least one D, and where every occurrences of OO must be followed (not necessarily immediately) by a
L. So that lines like:

> DO NOT FEED THE BEAR

Would be accepted. I've been told this is quite tricky and I've been having lots of difficulty with white spaces between words.

What I have so far is:

```
(?=[A-CE-Z]*D)(.*?OO(?=[A-KM-Z]*L)
```

Any help would be awesome!

Thank you!

Comment: If you've been having difficulty, you should have at least a couple of examples of what you've tried that you could include here. Please [edit] your question and provide them. Without doing so, this appears to be a homework question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this lookahead based regex:

```
^(?=[ A-CE-Z]*D)(.*?OO(?=[^L]*L)|(?!.*?OO)[A-Z ])*$
```

Explanation:

- `(?=[ A-CE-Z]*D)` --- Makes sure there is at least D in the input
- `(.*?OO(?=[^L]*L)|(?!.*?OO).)` --- see below

  - `.*?OO(?=[^L]*L)` --- if OO is there then it should be followed by at least L
  - `(?!.*?OO).` --- there is no OO

[image]

Comment: +1. Although I would change `[^D]` to `[A-CE-Z]` since the regex is supposed to be over `{A, B, …, Z}` only.

Comment: @RakeshKR: Thanks for adding that nice regex image.

Comment: -1 I don't often downvote purely based on implementation, but for this answer I'm making an exception: It is terrible. It may *work*, but is about 3 times longer than it needs to be.

Comment: I've softened slightly by removing my downvote, but I encourage you to always seek ways of simplifying and importantly reducing code where possible (while still maintaining readability of course)

Comment: @Bohemian: Thanks and points well taken. I'm all for simplifying.

Answer (score 0):

Anchored look aheads are the way to go:

```
^(?=.*D)(?!.*OO[^L]*$)[A-Z ]*$
```

Note that you don't need the character class `[A-CE-Z]`; `.*` is just fine (think about it and you should realise why).

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/MQ6D3loGFg) of this regex.

Comment: What about he doesnt want say `{ ~ / ; . , < > ( )` ? This is just wrong.

Comment: Please the problem again. oo is optional

Comment: @anubhava oops! Missed that (fixed now). Still, see how it doesn't need to be so long.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I didn't read it like that, but now I see I was just plain wrong. I have corrected it (I'm pretty sure)

Comment: @Bohemian: Removing my down-vote since you've rectified the regex.

Answer (score 0):

I like to separate the conditions in their own groups like so

`^(?!.*[^\sA-Z])(?=.*D)((?=.*OO.*L)|(?!.*OO)).*$`

- `(?!.*[^\sA-Z])` does not see anything other than the alphabet and white spaces
- `(?=.*D)` contains at least one "D"
- `((?=.*OO.*L)|(?!.*OO))` if it contains "OO" it must be followed by an "L" or does not see "OO"
- `.*` grab everything passes all conditions